# How to add two XMLgregorian calendar instance in Java

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar

I have two XMLGregorian varibales.

```
 XMLGregorianCalendar date;
 XMLGregorianCalendar startTime;
```

Date has only date value ie 2017-07-23 and startTime has only time ie 20:00:00.
I want to add the above two variables ie XMLGregorian variable which will have date + startTime.
Help me to achieve this.